# Firebase hosting throws - Error: HTTP Error: 400, Precondition check failed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting

Im getting a 400 error when running firebase deploy in my terminal after deploying my docker image in GCP.
I've checked that my firebase tools are up to date, but cant seem to find any other relevant information on this subject online.

All help or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Having the exact same issue. It worked yesterday at 19.54 (GMT+1) for us, but an hour later it stopped working, with "Error: HTTP Error: 400, Precondition check failed." as the error

Comment: Same. Stopped working today.

Comment: I found a ticket for it which is acknowledged by Google: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2949

Comment: This should be fixed now. It works for me :)

Comment: Thank you all, this was in fact an issue with firebase and this morning I was able to successfully deploy.